# Adding new words to Artha

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, dictionary

I have installed the offline dictionary **Artha** and have the latest version. It is a good dictionary but sometimes I do not find meaning of certain words. Can new words be added to its database? If possible how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artha uses the Wordnet Database and adding new words is quite expensive:

> The WordNet database is stored in an ASCII format consisting of eight files, two for each syntactic category. Additional files are used by the WordNet search code but are not strictly part of the database. All WordNet file formats are described in [Section 5](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/documentation/#Section5) of the WordNet manual. The page [wmdb(5)](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wndb.5WN.html) describes the format of the database files.

<sub>[Source](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/frequently-asked-questions/database/)</sub>

Comment: Can you please suggest a better dictionary whose database is regularly updated?

Comment: Sorry, not really. I use Google Translate.